# Repeat a Function until specified Action (Aruino IDE)

Tags: function, while-loop, arduino, exit, break

In my program I am displaying time on an OLED via bluetooth from an app I've created on MIT app inventor. While I'm displaying the strings of time I am using a function to search for an 'Up' Gesture from the 'Sparkfun APDS9660 Gesture Sensor'. Once I do an 'Up' gesture I would like to clear the display and show the string "camera". I would like it to stay in the 'camera' function (in code) while completing the tasks, until I do a down gesture to return to showing 'time' function.

```
void handleGesture() {
  if ( apds.isGestureAvailable() )
  {
    if(DIR_UP)
    {
      Serial.println("UP");
      Serial.println("Camera");
      display.setTextSize(1);
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.setCursor(0,20);
      display.println("Camera");
      display.display();
      Q = 0;

      while(Q == 0)
      {
        if (DIR_RIGHT)
        {
           digitalWrite(13, HIGH); 
           delay(1000);             
           digitalWrite(13, LOW);   
           delay(1000);
        }

        if (DIR_LEFT)
        {
          digitalWrite(12, HIGH); 
          delay(1000);             
          digitalWrite(12, LOW);   
          delay(1000);
        }

        if (DIR_DOWN)
        {
          break;
        }
      }   
    }  
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use a 'while loop' to repeat the code and then a 'break' to exit the code. If anyone knows any better solutions please comment.

Thanks for All Reply's

Comment: Also asked at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=490075

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this particular sensor, so I can't comment on whether you're reading the gesture correctly.

I'll assume you are, and that `handleGesture()` is acting as an event handler for an interrupt raised by the sensor. A better solution than `while` and `break` within the handler is to let your program be in one of a few explicit states (say 'camera mode' and 'time mode').

The gesture handler would just switch between them, and the actual logic would go in `loop` (or mode-specific functions, as expected).

This basically makes your program into a state machine. For example:

```
enum mode {
    camera,
    time
};

mode currentMode;

void loopCamera() {
    // 'Camera mode' code goes here
}

void loopTime() {
    // 'Time mode' code goes here
}

void setup() {
    // Set initial mode
    currentMode = time;

    // Other setup follows...
}

void loop() {
    switch (currentMode) {
        case camera:
            loopCamera();
            break;
        case time:
            loopTime();
            break;
    }
}

void handleGesture() {
    if (apds.isGestureAvailable()) {
        if (DIR_UP) {
            // Insert one-time code for switching to camera mode here
            currentMode = camera;
        } else if (DIR_DOWN) {
            // Insert one-time code for switching to time mode here
            currentMode = time;
        }
    }
}
```

This is preferable to putting all of your program logic in the handler because it clearly separates what the different functions are doing (the handler handles gestures, swapping your program's mode) and makes it easier to add functionality (modes, etc) in the future.

Comment: @Aidan.Thank you for your advice on the code. I've written it but the it still doesn't work as planned. I'm guessing it has to do with the Interrupts. but the Picture and Video flash repetitively (without swiping) and the time shows for a split second then disappears for about 1 second and then shows again. I'm I still doing something wrong.

Comment: I'll put the code in an answer because its to large for a comment.